# Significance of md5sum file in debian package source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, dpkg

I have one debian package source with md5sum file inside DEBIAN directory

```
|-- DEBIAN
|   |-- control
|   |-- md5sums
```

1. Now my question is when this file will be used?
2. Will it be useful for integrity check of each file inside debian package before installing debian package?
3. On machine when I install this debian package with manually modified md5sum(replaced some numbers in md5sum string) it doesn't show error, similar file is residing in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.md5sums` How can this be useful to check integrity of each file.

Answer (score 2):

So, here is a quick compilation to answer all your questions:

1. https://wiki.debian.org/MD5

> MD5 Sums are 32 byte character strings that are the result of running
>   the md5sum program against a particular file. Since it is very hard to
>   find two different files that results in same strings, MD5's can be
>   used to determine that the file or iso you downloaded is a bit-for-bit
>   copy of the remote file or iso.

2. You may use [debsum](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/debsums.1.html).
3. `dpkg` or `apt-get` don't check the `md5sum` before installing a package as you have already found out. The files you are talking about is used to verify if the packages have been altered after installation. See below:

https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.package-meta-information.html

> 5.2.3. Checksums, List of Configuration Files
>
> ...the control.tar.gz archive of a
>   Debian package may contain other interesting files. The first,
>   md5sums, contains the MD5 checksums for all of the package's files.
>   Its main advantage is that it allows dpkg --verify (which we will
>   study in [Section 14.3.3.1, “Auditing Packages with dpkg --verify](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.supervision.html#sect.dpkg-verify)”) to
>   check if these files have been modified since their installation. Note
>   that when this file doesn't exist, dpkg will generate it dynamically
>   at installation time (and store it in the dpkg database just like
>   other control files).

Comment: Now simple questing, will md5sum is useful while installing debian package? like when doing dpkg -i test.deb and test.deb has md5sum file inside it will it able to check md5sum before installing the package?

Comment: So the only advantage of having this file is to save time at install-time by pre-computing the md5sums?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the package *debsums*, then you can do a manual or scheduled verification of the installed packages.

Comment: I don't want to verify post installation, but before installation if this md5sum file is useful for integrity check?